# Finding maximum values of a function on an interval?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I took the derivative of the original function and then set it to zero and got
$$r= -2r0/((dv/dr0)-2)$$
Honestly, I'm pretty lost and need some help getting started. Thank you.

> [image]

Comment: OK, I think I see your problem, but I'll ask you these questions before I proceed:
(1) What *function* are you differentiating? 
(2) With respect to which variable are you differentiating it?

Comment: This is the question alone. No more info has been given. I think with respect to r because r0 will be a constant and so will k.

Comment: OK, so which function are you differentiating?

Comment: v(r) is the one I am differentiating.

Comment: Very good. Expand v(r) by multiplying out the terms completely (i.e., $r^2$ by the rest of the equation). Remember that $k, r_0$ are constants.

Comment: I did that and got v ' (r) = 2krr0-3k(r^2)

Comment: so then I set v'(r) = 0 and got r= -2/3(r0), is this correct so far?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18275/discussion-between-daonlybg-and-king-squirrel).

Answer (score 0):

So if $r_m$ is the maximum point of the function $v(r)$, then
$$ \frac{dv}{dr}|_{(r=r_m)} = 0 $$
We solve for $r$:
$$v'(r) = \frac{d}{dr}(k(r_0 r - r^3)) = 0$$
$$ \implies k(r_0-3r^2) = 0 \implies r = \sqrt{\frac{r_0}{3}}$$
That's our radius $r_m=\sqrt{\frac{r_0}{3}}$ at which $v$ is a maximum or a minimum. Next we calculate the second derivative:
$$ v''(r) = \frac{d^2v}{dr^2} = \frac{d}{dr}(k(r_0-3r^2)) = -6r$$
If we substitute $r_m$ for $r$, $$v''(r_m) = -6\sqrt{\frac{r_0}{3}}$$ which is less then zero. We know that if the second derivative at $r_m$ is less than zero, that point is a maximum point.
Then, the maximum velocity is $v(r_m)$: $$v(r_m) = k(r_0r_m-r_m^3)$$